# passing numeric value to scrolledtext widget in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "C:\Users\USER1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1702, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/USER1/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/newWidget.py", line 54, in clickedEvaluate
    txt.insert(END,s[i] +">>>>>>>>>" + Dicesim + "\n")
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "StringVar") to str
```

the text above shows the error message

```
Dicesim=StringVar()


def clickedEvaluate():
    if txt1.get()=='':    
        messagebox.showerror('Empty entry', 'You have not entered the required first text for comparison')
        txt1.focus()

    else:
        combo = Combobox(window)
        combo['values']= ('Dice', 'Bigram', 'Trigram', 'Set-Based','NS-Sim')
        combo.current(0) #set the selected item
        combo.grid(column=0, row=4)

        file=open('db_word.txt','r')
        s=file.readlines()

        txt = ScrolledText(window,width='50',height='10',wrap=WORD)
        txt.grid(column=1,row=6)
        #txt.pack()
        if combo.get()=='Dice':
            for i in range(20):
                Dicesim.set(dice(txt1.get(),s[i]))
                txt.insert(END,s[i] +">>>>>>>>>" + Dicesim + "\n")
                txt.yview(END)
```

The expected result is to display 
's[i] +">>>>>>>>>" + Dicesim + "\n"'. this in a line as `dice()` is performed, the `StringVar`, `Dicesim` is not recognised in `txt.insert` method.

Comment: Please fix the formatting of your code.

Comment: What did you not understand from: `TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "StringVar") to str`